# WPF C# Frame Navigation from page navigated

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

i've a windows and a frame in this windows.
the frame navigate in  a page and into this page i've a button.
The page was created dinamically so, i want to add a event onclick of button into the page, that permit me to navigate a new page into frame of window.

i'm writing on google about custom event that can permit me to raise an event in a page that is related to event in a window.

Can you help me please??

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to navigate from one page to another using a `event`?

If that is the case, take a look at the following links below - these will give you a better understanding of navigating through a WPF application providing examples and sample apps.

[How to Build, Manage and Navigate the User Interface of a WPF Application](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-Build-Manage-and-fdd0074a)

[Simple Navigation](http://www.paulstovell.com/wpf-navigation)

This is how I achieve it. In the code behind of your application, do something like this to help navigate to the next page for your click event;

```
private void btnClick_HomeClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     FrameContent.Navigate(new ExampleView()); //FrameContent is the name given to the frame within the xaml.
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi gregory, thanks for your answer, i should navigate from one page to others page but with event into one class . in a class i assigned a event onclick to a button, and in this event i must raise an event in mi mainwindow that contain a frame!

hope you can hel me!

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you're trying to say. I recommend you go through those two links I suggested or try and implement the code snippet I created for you. If I understand you correctly, you have multiple pages you want to navigate to. If thats the case, you could use a `Menu` or a `Ribbon` and use events to navigate through each page. Hope this helps.

Comment: i've resolved with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901007/sending-event-between-2-wpf-windows

Comment: Want to point out, that depending on what is on the page and how often you call for navigation, this can cause a memory leak as you are creating new instances of that class for each navigation without disposing of it. I like to use `new Uri("ExampleView.xaml", UriKind.Relative)` more because it seems to clean up after itself.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the scenario here is that he has a Window with a frame and the navigation method is also in this window.

What you can do is to pass your window to those dynamically created pages.

```
//Main Window
public class MainWindow
{
   public void NavigatePage(Page page)
   {
      YourFrameInstance.Navigate(page)
   }
 }

//Your Page
public class Page
{
    private readonly Window _mainWindow;

    public Page(Window mainWindow)
    {
       _mainWindow = mainWindow;
    }

    void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var page = new Page(_mainWindow);
        _mainWindow.NavigatePage(page);
    }
 }
```