# WPF - Handling window close in owner window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following code in WPF 4.5:

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        SepararStockView SSV = new SepararStockView(StockIDSeparar)
              {
                  Title = "Separar Stock",
                  ShowInTaskbar = false,               // don't show the dialog on the taskbar
                  Topmost = true,                      // ensure we're Always On Top
                  ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize,    // remove excess caption bar buttons
                  Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow,
              }; ;

    }
```

How i can handle the "close" of the "child" window ('SSV') to re-load a grid?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901007/sending-event-between-2-wpf-windows

Comment: If it's presented using `ShowDialog` the parent window will block until it has closed.

Comment: @Shoe so, i just add the load method for the grid i want to load after the SSV.show() that must work right?

Comment: `Show` does not block but `ShowDialog` does. You will have to register an event with the parent window to get it to work with `Show`

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an event in the child window.
2. Attach listener here in the main window when you are creating an instance of child window.
3. When closing child window raise that event so that it can be listened in the main window.