# How to use the slider in child window to control the image in main window in C# wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, image-processing

I need to create a new window with slider in it and use the slider to update the image in the main window. The slider is the threshold and the image will get changed according to the threshold number. I use c# wpf.
 I tried the method from here [Samich's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901007/sending-event-between-2-wpf-windows)

However, I had trouble about `this.Loaded+= new RoutedEventHandler(Child_Loaded)` it just doesn't work with the slider event `private void Slider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)`

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Clemens I updated what I have done. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you use delegate it will be easily solved!