# How to get a value from a public method in another class in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, getter

Context: I am making a WPF app. In this case I have a window with user controls and another windows with info introduced in the user controls. I have three windows: Main, where I create buttons, Data entering window (this data later go to the main to create the buttons, using a `showDialog()==true`) and the View button data in a detailed view.

Problem: I'm having problems when I want to get variables from another window to the view button info window. This window called Window4 doesn't receive the variables and so equals them to null.

Code:

```
//Click event of the new buttons created with data entering window's info.
void newBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Window4 win4 = new Window4();
    win4.Show();
}
...
var vent = new Ventanal2(); //Ventanal2 is data entering window
if (vent.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    ImageBrush nuestroIcono = vent.retornoIcono();
    string tituloHabilidad = vent.retornoTitulo();
    string grupoHabilidad = vent.retornoGrupo();
    int nivelHabilidad = vent.retornoNivel();
    //The method below creates the new button. The above get the button Data from the Data Entering Window
    crearBoton(tituloHabilidad, grupoHabilidad, nivelHabilidad, nuestroIcono);
}

//Data viewing window 
public Window4()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var vent = new Ventanal2();
    ImageBrush nuestroIcono = vent.retornoIcono();
    string tituloHabilidad = vent.retornoTitulo();
    int nivelHabilidad = vent.retornoNivel();
}
```

If I put a showDialog() if before the getters of the Data Viewing Window the Data Entering Window appears two times and that's not what I want.

What a Solution should look like:
I want to get the data introduced in Data Entering Window (then in my Button Creation Window) in my Data Viewing Window.

Thanks to everyone in advance.

Comment: Have you considered a single window app? Because that way your views and data would be hosted in one thing which instantiates all of them and can easily reference instances. You could do something similar with a mediator pattern. Passing around a reference to a mediator ( or dependency injection ) container which then acts as a "bag" holding references to all your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to keep your data separate from your views (windows)
What you could do here is have a class for all the data that each of your 3 windows can access. Then you can set the dataContext of your views to the instance of your data class so that bindings can access the data.
Pass in the instance of your data class when creating the windows
e.g. ShowMyView(MyData myData)
(for more info look at the MVVM pattern.)

Comment: Thank you. Just to make the work easier for anyone who tries to solve my question: what I did exactly was creating a new class and instancing the variables in the button creation from there, then I used these variables as properties of the Data Viewing Window and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass your values using events between your windows. Have a look at the examples of [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901007/sending-event-between-2-wpf-windows/7901042).

Comment: Where should I locate the variable instances so it gets the data in the correct moment?

Comment: You will be passing your data using the [event data functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/#event-data).
 So, basically according to your scenario, when the user introduces the data, you should be firing an event, from the data entering window, and the event will be carrying all the data with it. You can listen to this event in other places. For example, the Data viewing window receives that event and updates it's UI components accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the values in variables and pass these to `Window4`:

```
private ImageBrush _nuestroIcono;
private string _tituloHabilidad;
private string _grupoHabilidad;
private int _nivelHabilidad;

void newBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Window4 win4 = new Window4(_nuestroIcono, _tituloHabilidad, _nivelHabilidad);
    win4.Show();
}

...
var vent = new Ventanal2(); //Ventanal2 is data entering window
if (vent.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    _nuestroIcono = vent.retornoIcono();
    _tituloHabilidad = vent.retornoTitulo();
    _grupoHabilidad = vent.retornoGrupo();
    _nivelHabilidad = vent.retornoNivel();
    crearBoton(_tituloHabilidad, _grupoHabilidad, _nivelHabilidad, _nuestroIcono);
}

...
public Window4(ImageBrush nuestroIcono, string tituloHabilidad, int nivelHabilidad)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //use the parameters...
}
```

As a side note, it's a bad practice not to use English member names regardless of your native langauge.